# Find smallest $n$ such that $a$ divides $b^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers $\geq 2$.  I need to find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $b^n-1$ is divisible by $a$.  Is there an efficient algorithm for finding this, or do I need to use brute force?

I looked into this a bit and the answer seems related to Euler's totient function, but the only thing I've found so far is that if $m$ (the answer I'm looking for) is the smallest such $n$, then $m \leq \phi(a)$; I didn't find anything that would tell me how I could tell when $m = \phi(a)$ or if there were any other way to narrow down the possibilities so that I wouldn't have to check every number from $1$ to $\phi(a)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744480/589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you're looking for the smallest $n$ such that $b^n \equiv 1 \pmod a$. This is called the "order" of $b$.

First: let $k$ be any integer, not necessarily the smallest one, such that $b^k \equiv 1 \pmod a$. Can you show that $m$ divides $k$?

Second: there are many ways of showing that $b^{\varphi(a)} \equiv 1 \mod a$. ([Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem))

What does this imply about your $m$?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was called "order".  (Or "multiplicative order".)  That will help me look into it myself further, to see what efficient algorithms there might be for computing it.  So $m$ divides  $\varphi(a)$, which should help even if I can't find any other info.