# Length of digits before the period in decimal expansion for rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I'm a newbie with number theory and I've been reading [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalExpansion.html) and trying to figure out how to calculate the length of the digits before the period and digits of the period of a rational number of the form $m/n$.

I came up with the following steps but unfortunately this doesn't always work

1. Compute the prime factors for the denominator $n$
2. If there are 10-coprimes factors, there's a period otherwise there isn't
3. If there's a period, calculate its length taking each 10-coprime factor and doing the discrete logarithm $10^k\equiv 1 \pmod{factor}$ to find the maximum $k \le n$ (i.e. the maximum multiplicative order between the factors)
4. There are digits before the period only if the denominator $n$ can be expressed as $n_02^\alpha5^\beta$ (and $n_0$ is coprime to 10) so the length of the digits before the period is the maximum between 0, $\alpha$ and $\beta$

The approach above, however, doesn't work since I'm getting length of 1 for the digits before the period for a simple rational number like $124/6 = 20,\bar6$ (while the result should be 0). I suppose the error should be in step 4.

Comment: I don't even know what pre-cycle length means, if for $20.666\dots$ it is $1$. My inclination would be to call it $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I encountered some resources calling the period "cycle" and I probably misused the word to indicate the number of decimal digits before the period. I'll edit the question to make it more clear, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I recently tackled a similar problem and ended up asking [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943882/find-smallest-n-such-that-a-divides-bn-1).  Maybe some of the info will help.

Comment: I find it a bit strange, that your algorithm does not take the numerator into account. Surely $1/21$ is going to differ from $7/21=1/3$ in period length since numerator and denominator have common factors, @MarcoA. That could possibly fix your problem. So start by getting rid of $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: @String We're on the right track, I began experimenting and thinking the same as you a few minutes ago. It seems that I **must** take the numerator into account: take a look at the first line after equation `(5)` in the page I linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me elaborate a bit on my comments:

Suppose $n$ is coprime to $10$. Then we have $10^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$, and thus it follows that $10^k\equiv 1\pmod n$ for some $k$ dividing $\varphi(n)$. Choose the smallest such $k$. This corresponds to 3. in your suggested algorithm. Then $n$ must divide $10^k-1$ and so all prime factors of $n$ can be found in
$$
10^k-1=\overbrace{999......999}^{\text{the digit }9\text{ repeated }k\text{ times}}
$$
Now for any $r\in\mathbb N$ such that $r<n$ we then have
$$
\frac rn=\frac{d}{10^k-1}
$$
where $d<10^k-1$ so that the above rational is recognized as a number in $[0,1)$ having a recurring decimal expansion of length $k$. The digits of $d$ with zeros padded on the left if necessary will then be the digits of the $k$-cycle.

---

Suppose now we are given any coprime natural numbers $m,n$ where one of them possibly is not coprime to $10$. Then we may find the minimal $s\in\mathbb Z$ such that
$$
10^s\cdot\frac mn=\frac{m'}{n'}
$$
where $m',n'$ are coprime and $n'$ is coprime to $10$. In that case
$$
\frac{m'}{n'}=\frac{qn'+r}{n'}=q+\frac d{10^k-1}
$$
with $0\leq r<n$ and thus $0\leq d<10^k-1$. Since $s$ was chosen to be minimal, we cannot divide by $10$ any more times without the denominator sharing factors with $10$. Thus none of the decimals in $q$ will be recurring. In effect, $\frac{m'}{n'}$ has its digits *precisely* split into its recurring part and its non-recurring part by the decimal point. It will be of the form
$$
\frac{m'}{n'}=q.\overline{00...d}
$$
where the zeros are only padded to the left if necessary in order to match the period length, $k$. Finally we conclude that
$$
\frac mn=10^{-s}\cdot\frac{m'}{n'}=10^{-s}q.\overline{00...d}
$$
where $q$ is the non-recurring part and $\overline{00...d}$ is the recurring part. Here $s$ denotes the length of the antiperiod. Note that $s$ can also be negative as in
$$
54321.\overline{321}=10^3\cdot 54.\overline{321}
$$
which in this sense has an antiperiod of length $s=-3$. Also note that $m'$ will be divisible by either $2$ or $5$ or none of them, but never both since then a smaller value of $s$ would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

[String](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449660/length-of-digits-before-the-period-in-decimal-expansion-for-rational-numbers/1450189#comment2953754_1449660) was on the right track: the [page I linked](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalExpansion.html) states that one should first factorize possible common multiples and obtain

$$ r=\frac{p}{2^\alpha5^\beta} \quad p \not\equiv 0 \pmod {2,5} $$

That means, as in the example I posted ($124/6=20,\bar6$) that one should only consider the factor 3 in the denominator and get the number $0$ as antiperiod (digits before period) length.

The algorithm seems to work with the modification above: [full algorithm here](http://marcodiiga.github.io/formatting-repeating-decimals/) (any feedback on errors/problems most welcome, possibly with an issue [here](https://github.com/marcodiiga/marcodiiga.github.io/issues))

Answer (score 0):

---

### Idea

Check the reminder, till it repeat.
Because the following digits are decide by the reminder.
Once reminder repeat, the digits will repeat.

---

### How to impl

First make sure n is not co-prime with 10.

Then, assume `1` as the first reminder.

Then do `r = (r*10) % n`, untill `r == 1` again, the count of iteration is the length of cycle.

---

### Example code

```
int cycle(int n) {
    if (n % 5 == 0 || (n & 1) == 0) return -1; // check co-prime with 10,

    int fr = 1 ; // first reminder,
    // int fr = 10 % n; // this can also work,
    int r = fr;
    int c = 0;
    do { // search till reminder repeat,
        r = (10 * r) % n;
        c++;
    } while (r != fr);

    return c;
}
```