# If $2^x \equiv 2^4 + 2^4 \pmod 7$, then what is the value of $\mathbf x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

It's easy to figure out the answer which is 2. But I am trying to solve it in a different approach. My approach:

$2^x \equiv 2^4 + 2^4 \pmod 7
\Rightarrow x\log_2(2) \equiv 4\log_2(2) + 4\log_2(2) \pmod 7 
\Rightarrow x \equiv 4 + 4 \mod 7 
\Rightarrow x \equiv 8 \pmod 7 
\Rightarrow x \equiv 1 \pmod 7 $

Here, the answer is 1(false) but it supposed to be 2. It works if I do the modular operation by 6.

PS: I read somewhere that it is related to Fermat's little theorem, but can't figure it out. Can someone give a detail explanation on this?

Comment: Logarithms in modular arithmetic don't work quite like that. You need to take more care. Also, the logarithm of a sum is not the sum of logarithms, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem says $2^6\equiv1\pmod7$.  In fact, $2^3=8\equiv1\pmod7$.

$2^4+2^4=2\times2^4=2^5 $, so, because $2^3\equiv1\pmod7$, $2^{3n+5}\equiv2^4+2^4\pmod 7$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$

$(n>-2$ to avoid negative exponents).

So if $2^x\equiv2^4+2^4\pmod7$, then $x$ could be $3m+2$

(integer $m>-1$ to avoid negative exponents).

On the other hand, $2^{3m}\equiv2^0\equiv1$ and $2^{3m+1}\equiv2^1\equiv2,$

so these are not congruent to $4=2^2\equiv2^5=2^4+2^4\pmod7$.

Comment: Note:   $2^1$ and $2^2\not\equiv1\pmod7$;  Fermat's little theorem says $2^6\equiv1\pmod7$

Comment: Actually, $2^5 \equiv 2^2 = 4 \pmod 7$, so you should be saying something like $2^{5 + 3n} \equiv 2^5 \pmod 7$ or $2^{5 + 3n} \equiv 4 \pmod 7$. It's **not** true that $2^{5 + 3n} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan:  I had realized I made some errors.  How's the post now?  (I still might edit the comment)

Comment: I believe it's now correct. Although it's true that $n$ can be any integer, if $n \lt 0$ for $3n + 2$, then you get into "fractions", which if you consider inverses, it's still correct, but you may wish to put some sort of lower limits for $n$ (e.g., $-1$ for $3n + 5$ and $0$ for $3n+2$) to keep things somewhat simpler & more straightforward.

Comment: Note:  $2^{3n}\equiv2^0\equiv1$ and $2^{3n+1}\equiv2^1\equiv2$, so these are not congruent to $4=2^2\equiv2^5\equiv2^4+2^4\pmod 7$; Fermat's little theorem says $2^6\equiv1\pmod7$

Comment: You may wish to consider adding something like your Note comment above to the body of your answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan:  I took your suggestions.  I thought it was clever to use $2^4+2^4=2^5$, but in retrospect it's not hard to calculate that $2^4+2^4=16+16\equiv2+2=4\pmod 7$

Comment: What you have now looks very good. It's a great explanation not only for the OP, but also for anybody else who later reads your answer.

Comment: $5\equiv2\bmod 3\implies 3n+2$ for any positive n works and doesn't miss one.

Answer (score 1):

$\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ 2\,$ has order $\,\color{#c00}3,\,$ so the correct modulus for $\,\ell := \log_2$ is $\,\color{#c00}3\ $ (not $7),\,$ i.e.

$\bmod 7\!:\,\ \overbrace{2^{\Large x}\equiv 2^{\large y}}^{\Large a\,\ \equiv\,\ b} \iff 2^{\large x-y}\equiv 1\iff \color{#c00}3\mid x-y\iff\!\!\!\!\! \overbrace{x\,\equiv\, y}^{\Large \ell(a)\ \equiv\ \ell(b)}\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#c00}3}$

Hence if you redo the calculation using modulus $\,\color{#c00}3\,$ instead of $\,7,\,$ and use $\,2^{\large 4}\!+2^{\large 4} = 2(2^{\large 4}) = 2^{\large 5},\,$ then you will obtain $\,2^{\large x}\equiv 2^{\large 5}\pmod{\!7}\iff x\equiv 5\equiv 2\pmod{\!\color{#c00}3}$

**Remark** $ $ Regarding you question about the relationship to little Fermat, since $\, a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\,$ if $\,p\nmid a,\,$ this implies that the order of $\,a\,$ divides $\,p-1.\,$ For algorithms to compute the order and solve the discrete log problem [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744480/242)

Comment: Above we used the basic order property in the [Corollary here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\ \ $

Comment: From Euler's totient function, 
    $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 (mod n)$ where gcd(a, n) = 1 

If I use $log_a$ on both sides then the equation will be like below? 

$\phi(n) \equiv 0 (mod \phi(n))$ 

Am I correct? @Bill Dubuque

Comment: @PiasRoy No, the final comngruence should be modulo $\,{\rm ord}_n\,a.\,$ To obtain *all* the integer solutions this modulus must be the actual length of the cycle of powers of $a$ mod $n$, not some multiple of it (such as $\phi(n))\ \ $

Comment: E.g. $\,2^{\large x}\equiv 2^{\large 5}\pmod{\!7}\iff x\equiv 5\pmod{6}\,$ is wrong since it omits solutions $\,x\equiv 2\pmod{6}.\,$ Correct is that  $\,2^{\large x}\equiv 2^{\large 5}\pmod{\!7}\iff x\equiv 5\pmod{\!\color{#c00}3}\ \ $

Comment: Is there any algorithm to find $\,{\rm ord}_n\,a.\,$  efficiently? @BillDubuque

Comment: @PiasRoy See the thesis I coted in the linked answer. See also the [Order Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242)

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat’s little theorem, $2^6\equiv1\pmod7$, so if $x\equiv y\pmod6 $ then $2^x\equiv2^y\pmod7$.  So to solve $2^x\equiv2^4+2^4=32\equiv4\pmod7$, you only have to check if the following are congruent to $4\pmod7:  1,2,4,8,16,32.$  That’s easy, no?