# Minimal integer to make a rational into an integer

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, binary

Let $q = \frac ab$ be any rational number such that $a < b$. What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\frac ab \times  \left(2^n-1\right)$ is an integer?

Comment: By definition, that the order of $2$ $  \pmod b$.  Note that if $b$ is even, then there is no such $n$.

Comment: If $a,b$ have no common divisor, then search for the smallest $n$ s.t. $b$ divides $2^n-1$.

Comment: Is there an expression that might (approximately) relate $n$ to $b$?

Comment: There is no easy way to compute $n$, unfortunately.  General theory tells us that $n$ is a divisor of $\varphi(b)$, where $\varphi$ denotes [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)  In particular, $\varphi(b)$ always works as an exponent $n$, but it won't, in general, be minimal.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the binary tag? Are you trying to write a program for this?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Re: binary, see the first sentence in my answer.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in a small tangent in an answer. I'm asking the OP what interest *they* have in putting up the binary tag, since it may affect answers.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yuur response is quite puzzling. Do you *seriously* think that the reaosn is other than I have explained?  If so please do explain since that would be rather surprising. Btw, you need to use "<atsign>user" if you wish the user to be notified of your reply (I noticed it only by chance).

Comment: I'm not saying it probably isn't, but I'm not going to assume the reasoning behind the OP's tagging. That is why I am asking *them*. Also for some reason mobile is being buggy for me on the @.

Comment: @Sim  But it seemed you were by calling the question's raison d'etre a "small tangent" . That's why I was puzzled by your remark.

Comment: The majority of your answer is not specific to binary, hence my remark.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt and Bill Dubuque, thanks for the responses---I used the "binary" tag when posting the question for the same connection identified in Bill's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply the binary analog of [computing the decimal period of a fraction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140643/242)

W.l.o.g. generality we may assume that $\,a/b\,$ is reduced, i.e. $\,d = \gcd(a,b) = 1\ $ (else cancel $d).$

Then $\, (2^{\large n}-1)a/b = k\in\Bbb Z\iff bk = (2^{\large n}-1)a\ $  so $\,b\mid a(2^{\large n}-1).\,$ Since $\,\gcd(b,a) = 1\,$ we infer by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) that $\,b\mid 2^{\large n}-1,\,$ i.e. $\,2^{\large n}\equiv 1\pmod{\!b}.\,$

Since $\,2^{\large n}-1\,$ is odd its factor $b$ must be odd, and it is easy to show that such an $n$ must exist, e.g. by a pigeonhole argument, or by Euler's phi theorem (or Lagrange) we can choose $\,n = \phi(b).$

The least such $\,n > 0\,$ is known as the *order* of $\,2\,$ modulo $\,b.\,$ It can be verified using the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) and computed by [various algorithms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744480/242)