# On an Exponential Diophantine Equation of the form $g^y = ax + b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

Consider the Exponential Diophantine equation:

$$
2^y = 694 + 1387x \tag{1}
$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%202%5Ey%20%3D%20694%20%2B%201387x%20over%20the%20integers) gives the following solutions:

$$x = 94, y = 17$$

$$x = 24772702, y = 35$$

$$x = 6494015324254, y = 53$$

$$x = 1702367153161371742, y = 71$$

$$x = 446265334998334634066014, y = 89$$

If we observe the $y$ coordinates, we see a pattern:

$$17 = 17 \times 1 + 0$$

$$35 = 17 \times 2 + 1$$

$$53 = 17 \times 3 + 2$$

$$71 = 17 \times 4 + 3$$

$$89 = 17 \times 5 + 4$$

Now consider the Exponential Diophantine equation:

$$
3^y = 925 + 1387x \tag{2}
$$

Again, from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%203%5Ey%20%3D%20925%20%2B%201387x%20over%20the%20integers), we get the following solutions:

$$x = 36071770078586, y = 35$$

$$x = 5414179174462671091526111000906, y = 71$$

The pattern for the $y$ coordinates is

$$35 = 35 \times 1 + 0$$

$$71 = 35 \times 2 + 1$$

We did not construct the Diophantine equations (1) and (2) at random. In fact, they were carefully constructed by solving the equations

$$
2u - 1387v = 1 \tag{3}
$$

and

$$
3p - 1387q = 1 \tag{4}
$$

respectively. $u = 694$ is a particular solution of Eqn. (3) and $p = 925$ is a particular solution of Eqn. (4).

**Questions:**

1. Can we generalize that for an Exponential Diophantine equation of the form

$$g^y = ax + b \tag{5}$$

where $\gcd(g,a) = 1$ and $u = b$ is a particular solution to $gu - av = 1$ and if $y = y_0$ is a particular solution of Eqn. (5) then $y = 2y_0 + 1$ is also a solution of Eqn. (5)?

2. If the answer to Question 1 is affirmative, then can we use this fact to actually solve equations of the type Eqn. (5)?

*Note:* This question is related to this [other MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703441/perfect-power-values-taken-by-an-arithmetic-sequence) I had asked a few days ago.

Comment: When you consider sequence of division remainders of $2^y$ divided by $1387$ you will have periodical sequence after some position. That's because $2^{18+t}=2^t (189\cdot 1837+1)$ has the same remainder as $2^t$, so general solution for $y$ is $y=17+18k$, $k=0,1,...$

Answer (score 1):

The general solution can be found as follows.

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be any solution of $g^y=ax+b$ and let $X,Y$ be the solution of $g^y=ax+1$ with $y$ as small a positive integer.

Then **all** the solutions for $y$ are given by
$$y=y_0+nY.$$

NOTE

It is easy to see that such a $y$ will always give a solution because then
$$g^y=g^{y_0}(g^Y)^n=(ax_0+b)(aX+1)^n$$
where the RHS is clearly a multiple of $a$ plus $b$, as required.

EXAMPLE

In your first example you correctly obtained the formula $17(n+1)+n$.

Your answer can be put into the same form as the general formula because it can be written as $17+18n$.